# jQuery not loading on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this code I'm wanting to use and it won't respond. I know the code it right because it's on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/ztz4Lf23/

But when I copy-paste this code, it does nothing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
<html>
<head>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script>$('button').click(function(){        
    $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + $(this).text());
    //$('input:text').val($('textarea').text() );
    $('input:text').val($('input:text').val() + ' ' +  $(this).data('stuff'));
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<button data-stuff='stuff_Q'>Q</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_W'>W</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_E'>E</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_R'>R</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_T'>T</button>
<button data-stuff='stuff_Y'>Y</button>
<br/><br/>  
<input type='text'/>
<br/><br/>  
<textarea></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't find a syntax error though. Thanks in advance

Comment: looks ok. i presume the opening html and head tags are in there. Place the  script at the end of the page after the last html tag and see if it helps. thats the same as enclosing it in a document ready function -- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Tasos I posted an answer for this (Y)

Comment: @James111 i was typing while you posted your answer 20secs before :)

Comment: @Tasos Great minds think alike !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put you `Jquery Code` into a  `$(document).ready(function() { });`

### Like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <script>


$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $('button').click(function(){        
        $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + $(this).text());
        //$('input:text').val($('textarea').text() );
        $('input:text').val($('input:text').val() + ' ' +  $(this).data('stuff'));
    });
}); //End of document.ready
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting thing to remember: Code that manipulates the DOM needs to execute after the page finishes loading.

Funny thing about JSFiddle is it wraps all of your javscript in an onload listener by default. That's why it worked so well there but gave you trouble in the real world. You're not going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Here http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ is good resource for this.

I would like to wrap your following js code into

```
$(function(){
  // Your js code
});
```

It would be something like this,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$('button').click(function(){        
    $('textarea').text($('textarea').text() + $(this).text());
    //$('input:text').val($('textarea').text() );
    $('input:text').val($('input:text').val() + ' ' + $(this).data('stuff'));
}); 
});    
</script>
```